# Invalid Sum Operator

Tags: t-sql

A column of varchar data type whose values looks like:

01:23:21

00:45:00

10:00:00

05:01:04

need summing up. But as I do, I get the error:

"Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator."

How do I sum the above value while still retaining the format 00:00:00?

Thank you

Comment: What output you expect?

Comment: I want to be able to sum the data and still keep the same format.

E.g, total = 21:31:04

Answer (score 1):

Time does not support sum but datetime does

```
select convert(time, CONVERT(datetime, '00:45:00') + CONVERT(datetime, '01:00:04'))
```